# How does the windows DNS resolver hurt VPN software?

Tags: windows, dns, firewall, openvpn, windows-firewall

I recently came across the following article: https://medium.com/@ValdikSS/beware-of-windows-10-dns-resolver-and-dns-leaks-5bc5bfb4e3f1

This article explains that:

> Windows 10 DNS resolver sends DNS requests in parallel to all
>   available network interfaces and uses the fastest reply to come. If
>   you use DNS from the local network, this problem allows your ISP or a
>   hacker with Wi-Fi ap to hijack your DNS records even if you use VPN.

Can someone explain to me in more detail how this works? I would like to actually understand how the nature of the windows 10 DNS resolver allows someone to even get around a user's local VPN software to retrieve information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows a VPN redirects network packets requested and sent and listened and retrieved by Windows applications and the VPN would act as the default route for those applications. However some services like the Windows 10 DNS resolver can be requested by applications but do not use the default route. That part is explained in your article.

Because the application is requesting a windows service to itself make a DNS requests on its behalf this can (and based on the fastest reply logic, often does) bypass your VPN instead using the NIC or wifi.

Because DNS is usually nether encrypted nor authenticated you're relying on Wifi to encrypt and authenticate these messages. Or the physical security of a cable. Along with the trustworthiness of which ever ISP you may be connecting through to the DNS servers.

It's worth noting however that HTTPS checks DNS and will reject the connection if the DNS is wrong. However snooping is still possible.